# Ajaxified Average-Rating Bar won't reload in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rating

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails Application with a Rating System. The Rating is working fine so far. I also ajaxified it and it works. I also wanted to display the current Rating average in a Bar which length corresponds to the average value of all ratings.

The Bar's length is set as follows

```
var average = parseFloat( $(".rating_filled").attr("data-average") );

var avg_width = (average/5)*200;


$(".rating_filled").css("width", avg_width);
```

The value is being passed in the html as follows

```
    <div class="rating_bar">
        <div class="rating_filled" data-average="<%=@game.ratings.average(:value) %>"></div>
    </div>
```

Via ajax I reload the complete Partial that contains this bar and other Stats. Everything gets reloaded besides the bar. Once I submit a Rating I get the current average value, but the bar disappears completely. Firebug indicated that the bar itself receives the recent submitted value so this works fine, but the graphical part is missing.

So I guess it's because the javaScript file (where the graphical length is defined) does not get reloaded via ajax and therefore resulting in not displaying the bar at all.

I don't know whether I simply have to customize my jQuery commands to be up-to-date or even do something in my controller, passing the stuff via Json.

I don't know, could you guys help me out?
thanks a lot!

Comment: How are you reloading everything? You need to rerun the JS that you use to set the width initially. If you include the same lines in the JS where you reload the partial then you'll be in business.

Comment: well that's the point...it may be very basic, but how do I reload the JS? or do you mean I should embedd javascript in the html.erb partial? wouldn't that be offensive to the unobtrusive JS concept of rails?

Comment: It depends how you are reloading the partial - how are you re-rendering the partial into the page?

Comment: This is how I do it:                           $('.rating_stats').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'ratings/rating_stats') %>");             as I said the partial contains all Instancevariables, to display average and amount, and also that specific bar...only the bars graphical width is not reloaded...

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the whole partial where this line is called? I'm still not certain what the whole context is!

Answer (score 0):

This is what my partial looks like

```
<div class="rating_stats">
<div>
    Durchschnittswert:
    <span class="rating_avg">
    <% if !@game.average_rating.present? %>
        unbewertet
    <% else %>
        <%= @game.ratings.average(:value).round(2) %>
    <% end %>
    </span>
    <div class="rating_bar">
        <div class="rating_filled" data-average="<%= @game.ratings.average(:value) %>"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    Anzahl Wertungen: 
    <span class="rating_amount"><%= @game.ratings.count %></span>
</div>

<% if user_signed_in? %>
<p>
    Ihre Wertung :
    <span class="current_user_rating">

        <%= current_user_rating %>

    </span>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: embedding the javaScript code in the partial worked fine! Thanks for the good advice!